# Perl-cross some tests failing on target

Tags: perl, cross-compiling

Hi I've cross compiled Perl for my MIPS based router using Perl-cross.

Basic tests work, however the IO module is failing for some tests, notably `io_sel.t`, `io_sock.t`.

Using the debugger, I can see that the problem occurs (freezing) during a call to `IO::Select::can_write()`. The debugger freezes at line 122, the call to select(..).

My understanding of Perl's internals is limited, so am looking for advice on how to diagnose what the issue is. I'm assuming the issue is with the linking/wrapping against the c functions during the build?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, MIPS arch. has a lot of difficult issues for porting. So, I recommend pre-compiled perl binary and modules instead of manual build work.

Now Debian provides the Wheezy package that is minimum size( and stable) perl package file.
Debian's deb package file is just archived file. so, you can extract perl executable files/libraries from .deb packages and can install those to your router box.